# How to compile a Package using a psql command script

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

We are creating a wrapper script (This script will be used to setup a db i.e create schema , Create table , Create packages etc)  which will call multiple scripts within it. This is how we have made the entry for creating a packages in the wrapper script. This pkg cosists of multiple procedures.

\i RPT_glossary_pop_pkg.sql

Following is the output in the tracefile created :-

```
QUERY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE grs_rpt.grs_rpt_glossary_country_iou_pop_pkg 
IS   
PROCEDURE grs_rpt_glossary_pop_prc(); 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

FYI. PKG spec definition is :-

---

```
-- Package: grs_rpt.grs_rpt_glossary_country_iou_pop_pkg

-- DROP PACKAGE grs_rpt.grs_rpt_glossary_country_iou_pop_pkg;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE grs_rpt.grs_rpt_glossary_country_iou_pop_pkg
IS

PROCEDURE grs_rpt_glossary_pop_prc();
PROCEDURE grs_rpt_user_country_pop_prc();
PROCEDURE grs_rpt_user_iou_pop_prc();

END grs_rpt_glossary_country_iou_pop_pkg;
```

---

Is there a specific way to compile a package via such wrapper scripts?

Please Suggest.

Comment: We shouldn't be *guessing* what kind of RDBMS you are using...

Comment: what you mean? please make it simple anusha

Comment: Please clarify which RDBMS (database system) and version this is intended for. Add a tag - click `edit` under your question. I would have guessed PostgreSQL from your recent failed attempt, but there is not `CREATE PACKAGE` in the SQL dialect of Postgres.

Comment: We are using Postgres 9.1 version. 9.1 version does have Create PACKAGE feature. We are able to successfully compile and run the packages when using pgadmin.Only issue is compiling via psql script.

Comment: No, Postgres doesn't have `CREATE PACKAGE` command (see the list of available SQL commands [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-commands.html)). Are you, by any chance, using [Postgres Plus Advanced Server](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-plus-advanced-server/features-comparison) from EnterpriseDB?

Comment: yes we are using Postgres Plus Advanced Server from EnterpriseDB

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not support packages (I wish it did, to be honest).  There are two things that are relatively close.

The first is you can put your procedures in a schema for easy management.  This is similar to packages except that the namespace is shorter.

The second is that you can package procedures in a PostgreSQL extension.  This is a fairly extensive topic, and the best thing you can do is to start reading the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/extend-extensions.html).  This is a complex topic, so please read the documentation slowly and carefully a time or two before starting.